# Can a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ have finitely many local maxima, but infinitely many local minima ? What happens if $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, continuity, maxima-minima

Can a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ have finitely many local maxima, but infinitely many local minima ? What happens if $f$ is continuous ? I am aware of the fact that for a continuous function, between two local maxima, there is a local mimimum

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then it is not possible - for the reason you mention.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is allowed to be discontinuous, we can just take $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is not an integer, and $f(x) = x-1$ when $x$ is an integer. Infinitely many local minima, and zero local maxima.

Answer (score 0):

Not if $f$ is allowed to be discontinuous. Consider $|\sec(x)|$.